# cucumber-js: specify path for step-definitions file

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

I have multiple projects and I would like to implement cucumber-js E2E testing for all of them. I have a step definitions file which can be used for testing all of these projects, however I want to have multiple feature files with each project folder containing the feature files specific to the project. This is the layout:

step definitions:
projects/E2E/step_definitions/chat.js

feature files:
projects/project_1/features/feature_1.js

Right now, since the step definitions is outside of the features folder, I'm getting unimplemented steps error. Is there a way to specify the path to the step definitions when running cucumber-js?

Comment: How are you defining your steps and referencing them? Please provide some code samples.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the step definitions will be classed as a support file, which should mean you can include them like this:

`npm run cucumberjs -- --require "../E2E/step_definitions/*.js"`

**Note**

This assumes that your package.json is inside your `project_1` directory and includes:

```
"scripts": {
    "cucumberjs": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js"
},
```

**Reference**

CucumberJS Official Documents for [Requiring Support Files](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#requiring-support-files)